# Python - OpenCV search until good enough match found and stop

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv

I have a signature:

```
def find(outer: ndarray, inner: ndarray, precision: float) -> tuple[int, int] | None:
```

Where `outer` is image in which to search for `inner` image (for are RGB numpy arrays).
`precision` is 0..1 match: 1 is full pixel-perfect match, 0 is anything at all.
If any match with satisfactory precision found, return its top-left corner, else None. It doesn't matter which match is returned: the most precise or any other.

My code for that is

```
    comparison = cv2.matchTemplate(outer, inner, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    _, max_val, _, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(comparison)
    return max_loc if max_val >= precision else None
```

Which works fine, `TM_CCOEFF_NORMED` was chosen because it's the closest to that 0..1 precision and I can directly compare it.

Issue: this takes the same amount of time when `inner` is there as when it's not. I would like it to stop when first match is found, and then just fetch the coordinates.

Is it possible to do it this way?

Comment: I do not believe that you can do that in OpenCV. Also I do not recommend using TM_CCOEFF_NORMED. I would suggest using TM_SQDIFF_NORMED or TM_CCORR_NORMED as better metrics.

Comment: @fmw42, huh, you're right, after some testing TM_CCORR_NORMED seems to give very good results, especially on small images. Thanks.